# input field saved passwords on wrong input field

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, input

I have a few input fields on my website. There are few passwords saved for that website(Chrome Login Saved passwords). But the problem i am facing is that the email is appearing on the input field which is not for email i.e somewhere else on that same website. This is the input field code where i don't want chrome to autofill/autocomplete as it is not required here. I have tried autocomplete =off/false/new-password nothing worked.

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="week_sco_topic" placeholder="Week SCO Topics"  autocomplete="off">
```

When you click on the field above it shows the saved passwords for that website which is not required on this field.

Comment: can you please elaborate what are you trying to do,and what results are you expecting?

Comment: please explain in details and show proper code

Comment: Because of reputation i wasn't able to post the screenshot. However, i have elaborated the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The browser ignores autocomplete="off" unless it is in a form. Therefore, the code below removed the autofill suggestions.

```
<form autocomplete="off"><input type="text" ng-model="week_sco_topic" placeholder="Week SCO Topics"></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Google chrome ignores `autocomplete="off"` so you can try to make another input field above it to fool the browser

```
<input type="text" style="visibilty:hidden">

<input type="text" ng-model="week_sco_topic" placeholder="Week SCO Topics"  autocomplete="off">
```

you can also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15917221/5157756)

Comment: Did you check the answer in the link ?